# Make Menu-Item go to Home, then scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, menuitem

On my home page I have a series of Div's with content in them. Users can navigate to the div's quickly using menu-items which when clicked will scroll the page to the relevant div. Using the link "Beast Balls" (.beast-balls) and the relevant div for that link (.cat-beast-balls) the code for such a function is as follows:

```
$( '.beast-balls' ).on( "click", function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: (($( ".cat-beast-balls" ).offset().top) - 150)
    }, 1000, scrollHandler2);
});
```

So my question is, when a user is **not** on the home page, I would like the user to be able to click on the .beast-balls link, be redirected to the home page, and then scrolled to the .cat-beast-balls div.

How might I go about acheiving this?
Thanks!

Comment: are you passing any variables in through the url? Like, www.whatever.com/beast-balls....

Comment: Would it be possible to add unique anchors to the divs then direct to the like site.com/home#anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a click event carry over to another page like this. You should be using anchors to get to this content and overriding the default event of the anchor:

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="#cat1">Section 1</a>
 <a class="nav-link" href="#cat2">Section 2</a>

 <div class="section" id="cat1">
    Section 1
 </div>

 <div class="section" id="cat2">
    Section 2
 </div>
```

Then to handle other pages, just have your links set up there like this:

```
<a href="home.html#cat1">Go to section on home</a>
```

And in your jQuery to handle this you can run a function to see if there is an anchor in the url and run it:

```
function pageScroll(section) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: (($(section).offset().top) - 150)
    }, 1000, scrollHandler2);
}

function checkHash(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if(hash){
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        pageScroll(hash);
    }
}

$( '.nav-link' ).on( "click", function(e) {
    var location = $(this).prop('hash'); // Get Anchor
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser from going to that anchor
    pageScroll(location);
});

// Assumes you have a class of 'home' on your body or somewhere on the page, so you only run this on the home page
if($('.home').length > 0){
    checkHash();
}
```

Another reason you should be using anchors, is if JS fails your content would still navigate as usual without the effects. Linking to sections via classes takes away this feature and makes it an accessibility concern.

Comment: This looks good in theory! But when implementing I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" whenever I click on a .nav-link item

Comment: Ahhhh, will it make a difference if the 

    <div class="section" id="cat1">
    </div>

Is being loaded in by AJAX?

Comment: Glad to hear! Wanted to codepen/jsfiddle it but you can't check hash on those tools. Hope the errors were few and far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, passing a variable in through the url.
Then, in your homepage script, after the page is loaded, grab that variable and then use it to trigger a click on those menu items for whichever section they need to go to.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I got it now. Do you want to get access to the home window and animate it once the user has left the other page of your site. Right? You shouldn't use an a tag to access other pages. You should try styling the .beastballs to look like and behave like a link. Then, use jquerys open("www.siteName.com", "WinName") method to open your home page url. Make sure to record it as a variable like Home = open("URL", "Home") then

Locate the Home.location instead of using location in the animate. I'm really sorry if I didn't help you :(

Answer (score -1):

Don't know a lot about the ".on" method, but try using $("body") instead of using $("html,body"). Sorry if it didn't work
Also, make sure this "Scroll:Top", is valid, never heard of it

Comment: Hi Ethan, this made no difference. As the question states, "when a user is **not** on the home page" So the answer needs to redirect them to the home page if they aren't on it, then scroll to the content